# Bazel test returns checksum mismatch error for private GitHub repos

Tags: git, github, bazel, checksum, sha

I am trying to run some tests present on a GitHub repo. The repo depends on some other private repo available on my company's GitHub. They haven't really provided me with a Readme to run the tests, but I have a Makefile in the project that I am using. This is the Bazel command they are using for building the tests:

```
bazel \
--host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts' \
--host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword='changeit' \
test --features=race //test/e2e/...
```

**NOTE:** I had to add `--host_jvm_args` arguments because otherwise the command was failing with a `SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` error.

But, on running the above command, I get this error:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_github_pie_<company>_<repo-name>_bazel_prettier':
   java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.pie.<company>.com/<repo-name>/bazel-prettier/archive/v0.0.2.tar.gz] to /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<my-user-name>/492c2b2abdc487331e7cccd373c45b9c/external/com_github_pie_<company>_<repo-name>_prettier/v0.0.2.tar.gz: Checksum was 9148ae6fb489b66238cf3b003ae22b107e00ab2583856ee81659967f2245ba46 but wanted 9d64c8d1301b78ddf87ac2774fccbe28006448d000838cb92441cc7997455426
```

I am unable to find a possible cause of this error online. Can someone guide me to what could be the cause and a possible solution to fix this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

```
Checksum was 9148ae6fb489b66238cf3b003ae22b107e00ab2583856ee81659967f2245ba46 but wanted 9d64c8d1301b78ddf87ac2774fccbe28006448d000838cb92441cc7997455426
```

There is something like this in the `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` file - or something that is "included" by those files:

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_grail_bazel_toolchain",
    sha256 = "9d64c8d1301b78ddf87ac2774fccbe28006448d000838cb92441cc7997455426",
    strip_prefix = "bazel-toolchain-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain/archive/master.tar.gz"],
)
```

Just change the `sha256` checksum to that one Bazel suggest or remove it.

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: Could be `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` or something that is "included" by those files

Comment: I made the change to the expected checksum but now there is a new checksum that causes this error. It looks like a new checksum is being generated on every make and it compares with the the given in the file and then throws this error again.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you've changed the version but leaved the old sha256. It's better to keep correspondence between version number and checksum.